# Sequence of ranges including the last pair as a generator

Tags: python, range, generator, sequence

I have ranges like these :

```
  list(zip(range(1,1152,200),range(200,1351,200))) 
  [(1, 200), (201, 400), (401, 600), (601, 800), (801, 1000), (1001, 1200)]

  list(zip(range(1,401,100),range(100,511,100))) 
  [(1, 100), (101, 200), (201, 300), (301, 400)]
```

As you can see I'm missing the last pair : **(1201,1350) and (401,510)**

The question how to add it, but keep the thing GENERATOR i.e. lazy (the list() here is for display purposes)

The logic is sequence of ranges where N  .. M, Step :

```
 [ (N,N+S), (N+S+1, N+2S), (N+2S+1, N+3S), ... up to (N+xS+1,M) ]
```

Comment: how about writing custom generator?

Comment: Why not `list(zip(range(1,1152+200,200),range(200,1351+200,200)))`?
`range(start, end, step)` does not include end so make it. range(start, end+step, step)`